# Файлы из папки только по внутреннему запросу через Apache

Tags: php, файлы, apache, nginx

Пытаюсь реализовать раздачу файлов из защищённой папки средствами apache по внутреннему запросу через скрипт на php. Nginx   использовать не могу по обстоятельствам заказчика. В nginx есть удобное решение моей задачи:

```
location /dir{
  internal;
  mp3;
}
```

Как это можно сделать на apache?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.readfile.php ?

Comment: Это, к сожалению не поможет. Раздача файла работает нормально. Вопрос в настройках сервера.
Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы при вызове через скрипт файл был доступен, а при запросе по прямой ссылке возвращал ошибку. В nginx этого можно добиться с помощью настроек папки. А вот можно ли этого добиться на apache?

Comment: дак уберите вообще из вэб-рута ее и все, очевидно вроде?

Comment: Да, это можно было бы сделать, на выделенном сервере. Но у заказчиков просто хостинг с доступом по ssh. Так что всё, что мне доступно это bash скриты и htacess.
Я отредактировала вопрос, чтобы моя задача была наглядней.